# Windows 10 IoT WebCam - Microsoft LifeCam VX-700

Tags: webcam, iot, windows-10-iot-core

This webcam (Microsoft LifeCam VX-700) can record from Rasberry Pi 3 Model B. The FPS is somewhere from 3-5 FPS on this sample https://codeload.github.com/ms-iot/samples/legacy.zip/master (WebCamSample). Anyway to improve the FPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this slow framerate is that there currently isn't an optimized GPU driver that enables hardware acceleration to its full potential.

When you look at the Device Portal (admin site of the device on port 8080) you will notice in the performance tab that it mentions GPU but can't show any statistics. As soon as we get a build that includes the new driver I expect us to see some metrics there and vastly improved video performance.

This is a know issue, a big one as well, but as far as I understood people are working on it.

Lowering the resolution will help, obviously.